# Return Link Addresses of Titles on Google SERP

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying to get all link addresses that are hyperlinked on titles for a Google Search results page. Also trying to append it to a CSV file which I think I've got pretty straight as of now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
import re
import csv

#f = open("web_search_terms.txt", "r")

terms = ["thanks","for","the help"]

terms = []
for line in f:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  terms.append(stripped_line)


with open("web_urls.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Search Term", "URL"])
    for t in terms:
        url = f"https://google.com/search?q={t}"
        print(f"Getting {url}")
        html_page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, "html")
        divs = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "yuRUbf"})
        for item in divs:
            writer.writerow([t, item.get_text(strip=True)])
```

I'm not able to append the links to the "divs" list though, not sure how to get the hrefs within the class labelled "yuRUbf"

Any help would be super appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To get correct response from the Google server, set `User-Agent` HTTP header. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}


url = "https://google.com/search"
terms = ["thanks", "for", "the help"]

for t in terms:
    params = {"q": t, "hl": "en"}
    print(f"Getting {t}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    divs = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "yuRUbf"})
    for div in divs:
        print(div.a["href"], div.a.text)

    print()
```

Prints:

```
Getting thanks
https://slovnik.aktuality.sk/preklad/anglicko-slovensky/?q=thanks Preklad slova „ thanks ” z angličtiny do slovenčiny - Slovnik.skhttps://slovnik.aktuality.sk › preklad
https://slovnik.aktuality.sk/preklad/anglicko-slovensky/?q=thanks%21 Preklad slova „ thanks! ” z angličtiny do slovenčiny - Slovnik.skhttps://slovnik.aktuality.sk › preklad
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thanks Thanks | Definition of Thanks by Merriam-Websterhttps://www.merriam-webster.com › dictionary › thanks
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thanks THANKS | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionaryhttps://dictionary.cambridge.org › dictionary › thanks
https://www.thanks.com/ Thanks: Thank Homehttps://www.thanks.com
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/thanks Thanks Definition & Meaning | Dictionary.comhttps://www.dictionary.com › browse › thanks
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thank Thank definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionaryhttps://www.collinsdictionary.com › dictionary › thank
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnpZQoAOUFw THANK YOU and THANKS - How to thank someone in Englishhttps://www.youtube.com › watch

Getting for
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for For | Definition of For by Merriam-Websterhttps://www.merriam-webster.com › dictionary › for
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for For Definition & Meaning | Dictionary.comhttps://www.dictionary.com › browse › for
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for Meaning of for in English - Cambridge Dictionaryhttps://dictionary.cambridge.org › dictionary › for
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for FOR (preposition, conjunction) definition and synonymshttps://www.macmillandictionary.com › british › for
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for For definition and meaning - English - Collins Dictionaryhttps://www.collinsdictionary.com › dictionary › for
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/for For - definition of for by The Free Dictionaryhttps://www.thefreedictionary.com › for
https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/for 1 for - Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionaryhttps://www.learnersdictionary.com › definition › for

Getting the help
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454029/ The Help (2011) - IMDbhttps://www.imdb.com › title
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Help_(film) The Help (film) - Wikipediahttps://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › The_Help_(film)
https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/09/viola-davis-the-help-regret Viola Davis Regrets Making The Help: “It Wasn't the Voiceshttps://www.vanityfair.com › Hollywood › viola davis
https://www.csfd.cz/film/277770-cernobily-svet/prehled/ Černobílý svět (2011) | ČSFD.czhttps://www.csfd.cz › film › prehled
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_help The Help - Rotten Tomatoeshttps://www.rottentomatoes.com › the_help
https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/movies/2020/06/08/the-help-isnt-helpful-resource-racism-heres-why/5322569002/ 'The Help' isn't a helpful resource on racism. Here's why - USA ...https://www.usatoday.com › story › movies › 2020/06/08
https://www.amazon.com/Help-Emma-Stone/dp/B004A8ZWVK The Help : Emma Stone, Octavia Spencer, Jessica - Amazon ...https://www.amazon.com › Help-Emma-Stone
https://www.amazon.com/Help-Kathryn-Stockett/dp/0399155341 The Help: Stockett, Kathryn: 9780399155345 - Amazon.comhttps://www.amazon.com › Help-Kathryn-Stockett
https://www.martinus.sk/?uItem=258803 Kniha: The Help (Kathryn Stockett) - Anglický jazyk - Martinushttps://www.martinus.sk › ...
```